# Count unique values that are grouped by in Python

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by, unique

I am using a python database and am using pandas. Currently my database shows something like this:

```
Employer        Account_Num
AAA             123
BBB             456
AAA             789
AAA             123
BBB             101
CCC             112
```

I am able to put it into a table that counts all the Account_Num, which looks like this:

```
Employer   Account_Num
AAA        3
BBB        2
CCC        1
```

I used this code to achieve the above:

```
bigdata.groupby(['Employer'])[['Account_Num']].count()
```

But I only need the unique Account_Num's counted. Which should look something like this:

```
Employer   Account_Num
AAA        2
BBB        2
CCC        1
```

What is the best way I can achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`nunique()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html).

```
df.groupby('Employer').Account_Num.nunique()
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df.groupby('Employer').Account_Num.nunique()

Employer
AAA    2
BBB    2
CCC    1
Name: Account_Num, dtype: int64
```